# How to check if a date is within a given range in Microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data sheet with 6 columns which shows location, class, code, plan, start date, and end date. These dates show the block dates that needed to be illustrated in another sheet. I need a formula to input “X” for all the blocked days in the 2nd sheet which is more visual (note: not only for the start and end date, but also for all the days within that range).

```
    Class   
    Code-plan 1 Code-plan 2 Code-plan 3 Code-plan 4 Code-plan 5 
Date             X          
Date                 X   X
```

Comment: I presume that you understand what you're saying. Nobody else does. *Show* us what your input looks like -- it doesn't have to be your real, secret data; just something that looks real enough that we can understand what's going on. Also, explain it better. Then show the output corresponding to your input data, and explain it better, too. Then make the examples look the way they're supposed to look. Read our help on how to markup (markdown) text. Hint: don't use tabs.

Comment: A hint: You can use the **IF** function. You need to a put formula, where you want **X** to be displayed. Something like =IF(Condition,CHAR(88),CHAR(32)). So if the condition is true it will display **X**, else BLANK. Now work on the _Condition_ part of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **A1** contains a start date and **A2** contains an end date and we want to know if *today* is between them, pick another cell and enter:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>=A1,TODAY()<=A2),"in the range","not in the range")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful. Is there anyway to substitute A1 by a column, so the formula can be used for all the days in other cells too?

Comment: In other words, the formula needs to be dynamic to compare today's date with all the start and ending dates in the column